# stringstream or ostringstream for writing in file?

Tags: c++, std, stringstream, ostringstream

To write data from `ostringstream` to a `ofstream`, I have to write something like this:

```
std::ostringstream ss;
myFile<<ss.str();
```

on the other hand, if I use the `stringstream` I can access directly the buffer:

```
std::stringstream ss;
myFile<<ss.rdbuf();
```

The problem is that `ostringstream::str()` makes a copy of the string which is kind of bad because in my program there are very huge strings, so `stringstream` should be better because I can access directly the buffer for reading. And people here say that we should use `ostringstream` over the `stringstream` if we deal only with output operations. I can't simply use a string because I am inserting various type of data. So could someone give me an advice on how to deal with this?

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't skip the stringstream altogether and send the output directly to the file?

Comment: By writing each bit of data directly into the file, the processing time for the same file has increased a bit, so I was trying to make my app as fast as I can. I have found that inserting medium sized chunks of data works best, I am not really sure why.

Comment: Stupid question maybe: Are we sure that the `streambuf` at `.rdbuf` is correct? That it contains nothing more and nothing less than the entire contents that have been written to the `stringstream` so far? Does buffering have an effect? Nobody would expect `cout.rdbuf()` to remember everything that has been written to `cout` so far in the program?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid That's why he needs an `iostream`-derived class instead of an `ostream`, which would be more like `cout`. It is true, though, that different kinds of streams behave differently when mixing read and write operations. To be generic and support files etc, it would be better to explicitly call `ss.seekg` to go back to the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> people here say that we should use ostringstream over the stringstream if we deal only with output operations

The main reason for using the more specific `ostringstream` is to make your intentions clear and avoid mistakes. In this case `stringstream` is needed to prevent copying a potentially large string, so just use it (carefully).

Answer (score 3):

`ostringstream` is intended for cases where data goes into the stream and never comes out. (Except, of course, for the `std::string` object that you actually want.)

`stringstream` is intended for uses where reading and writing both occur. `<< rdbuf()` is a way of reading from the stream, so `stringstream` is completely appropriate.